# Pinwheel- perimeter of semicircular region

Tags: circles

[image: pinwheel]

Above, we have a larger circle of $r=16$ with 8 equally spaced semicircles of radius=8. Each semicircle has one end on the larger circle's center and the other on the circumference of the larger circle. Find the perimeter of the shaded region.

---

The circumference of the larger circle is $32\pi$ and it's divided into 8 parts, which makes the part of the perimeter of the shaded region resting on the larger circle measure $4\pi$ units. Both semicircular arcs measure $\pi r_2$ units = $8\pi$ units. So we have a perimeter of $8\pi+8\pi+4\pi = 20\pi$.

I feel like I might be misinterpreting the question, though- can you think of any other ways to interpret the question?

Comment: I think you're right.